# How to search with sub collections properties in RavenDB client api

Tags: ravendb

As the title says I would like to know how can use the Session.Query.Search(...) from RavenDB C# client API to do a full text search in property of a collection which is a property of an entity.

```
public class Order
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In pure RQL (raven query language) the query would be like this:

```
from Orders where search(Products.Name, '*alice*')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the client api,
use a **static index** to define which document field will be searchable.

After that, you can query this indexed field and get the documents that contain the term you search for in that indexed field.

See example in:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-with-static-index-single-field